# Javascript: How to get first random number always to be higher than the second random number

Tags: javascript, function, random, numbers

```
        $(function() {  
            var number = document.getElementById("breuken");        

            var i=0;

                for (i=1;i<=10;i++){
                    var fRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
                    var sRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);

                    var calc = fRandom - sRandom;

                    number.innerHTML += "" + fRandom + " - " + sRandom + " = " + calc + "<br />";
                }       

            number.innerHTML;
        });
```

Basically, what it does now is it shows 2 random numbers under 10. it subtracts the second number from the first number.

What I would like is to have the first number always be higher than the second number so I won't get any answers like '-3'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use `Math.abs()` ?

```
var calc = Math.abs(fRandom - sRandom);
```

In case orders are important, you can also do

```
                var sRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);

                // lower bound of sRandom, upper bound of (10 - sRandom)
                var fRandom = Math.floor(sRandom + Math.random()*(10-sRandom));
```

Comment: In this case OP has to change order to make displayed expression correct

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to take the absolute value:

```
var calc = Math.abs(fRandom - sRandom);
```

But since you're also listing the first and second numbers, you probably want to sort the values and re-store them, using min and max values:

```
var bigRandom = Math.max(fRandom, sRandom);
var lilRandom = Math.min(fRandom, sRandom);

var calc = bigRandom - lilRandom;

number.innerHTML += "" + bigRandom + " - " + lilRandom + " = " + calc + "<br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

Either

```
var fRandom = Math.floor(5 + Math.random()*5);
var sRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
```

or just call `Math.abs()` on the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the second number in the [0;fRandom] range:

```
var fRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
var sRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*fRandom);
```

or just swap the values :

```
var fRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
var sRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
if(sRandom<fRandom) {
    var temp = sRandom;
    sRandom = fRandom;
    fRandom = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need random numbers like this, use

```
var fRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
var sRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*fRandom);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add more line before subtracting:

```
if(fRandom < sRandom)
     fRandom = (sRandom - fRandom ) + Math.floor((Math.random() *10));
```